# How can I configure my shells to record all commands

Tags: ubuntu

I am running ubuntu 12.04, how can I configure my shell/ubuntu so that 
'history' commands will display all the previous command from different shells?

Basically, I want to a list of my previous command regardless which shell I enter.

Thank you.

Comment: What shell are you using? The default one for ubuntu is `bash`.

Comment: i am using bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the location of each shell's history file to be the same.

I don't know if that will work if you have multiple, different, interactive shells open -- I know two interactive bash logins will cooperate their usage of the history file. I'd bet the different shells just use standard, cooperative file locking. So they'll probably be just fine. I digress.

eg for bash 'export HISTFILE=/home/someuser/.my_cross_shell_history' and then the parallel for each shell you use.